# How to remove duplicated title in crystal report via C# in windows form application

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

Please refer to the following picture.
I have a dataset called dsCompanyRecords and the contents are shown in the picture.
I wanna create a crystal report, but it generated a duplicated title, pls see the picture.
How do I remove the duplicated line "RecordDate, In, Out, Balance, Comment"

The way I created the crystal report 
1. create a dataset called dsCompanyRecords.xsd
2. put a table in dsCompanyRecords.xsd, the columns are "ID, Company, CompanyId, Country,RecordsDate, In, Out, Balance, Comment"
3. create a crystal report called rptCompany.rpt 
4. Adjust the layout in crystal report 
5. Coding in source file,

```
  dsCompanyRecords ds = new dsCompanyRecords();  
  sqlDA.Fill(ds,"TCompany"); //Fill the dsCompanyRecords from my database
  ReportDocument myReport = new ReportDocument();
  myReport.Load("rptCompany.rpt");
  myReport.SetDataSource(ds);
  crystalReportViewer.ReportSource = myReport;
```

dsCompanyRecords has one table (TCompany) only.

Develop environment:
Windows 7 + VS2010 + CrystalReport13

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you placed the records headears (RecordDate, In, Out, etc.) into Details section instead of Page Header section

Comment: Oh,yes. I am new on crystal report, just now I changed layout, and I got the expected layout. Thanks